# XPath filtering on attribute with namespace

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

I need to create XPath expression to filter based on attribute that is in given namespace. Example XML is:

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
  xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'> ...
 <entry>
  <media:group>
   <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/1.jpg' yt:name='default'/>
   <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/2.jpg' yt:name='hqdefault'/>
   <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/3.jpg' yt:name='start'/>
   <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/4.jpg' yt:name='middle'/>
  </media:group>
 </entry>
```

And I need to get the url of the node with attribute yt:name set to 'hqdefault'.

I tried with XPath expression

```
'./media:group/media:thumbnail[@yt:name='hqdefault']/@url'
```

but it seems that specifying namespaced attribute with yt:name does not work. I get an empty DOMNodeList upon making a query.

I am accessing XML in php, so I registered yt namespace:

```
registerNamespace( 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' );
```

Thnx in advance

Comment: "does not work" - you need to say what happens. An error message?

Answer (score 9):

That XPath looks correct.

It could be that your library doesn't support namespaced attributes, or that you haven't properly registered the `yt` namespace and/or the `media` namespace.

**Try just matching on the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` inside of predicate filters, rather than using the namespace-prefix:**

```
./*[local-name()='group'
      and namespace-uri()='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
    ]/*[local-name()='thumbnail'
         and namespace-uri()='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
         and @*[local-name()='name'
                 and namespace-uri()='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'
                 and .='hqdefault'
                ]
        ]/@url
```

If this works, then there is an issue registering the namespaces for those namespace-prefixes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the rest is in order, simply replace the first `.` in the xpath with `/` to get `//media:group/...`  (or begin with `/atom:feed/media:group/...` and register the atom namespace).

Here's a complete working example:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( <<<XML
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
  xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
  <entry>
    <media:group>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/1.jpg' yt:name='default'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/2.jpg' yt:name='hqdefault'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/3.jpg' yt:name='start'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/4.jpg' yt:name='middle'/>
    </media:group>
  </entry>
</feed>
XML
);

$x = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$x->registerNamespace( 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' );
$x->registerNamespace( 'media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' );
$l= $x->query( "//media:group/media:thumbnail[@yt:name='hqdefault']/@url" );
for ($i=0; $i<$l->length; $i++) var_dump( $l->item($i)->value );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `yt` namespace prefix is used in your example XML, but is not declared. If that example XML is really all there is, it's not well-formed XML (in namespace terms). Therefore no generic XML tools, such as XSLT, are likely to be able to process it.

On the other hand if there is a declaration of the `yt` namespace prefix somewhere in your source document that you haven't shown us, then you need to declare in your XPath processing environment (XSLT I guess) a prefix for the same namespace URI. E.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:yt="theNamespaceURIForYT">
```

XPath is not aware of any namespace prefix declarations that occur in the source document. It only knows what namespace (URI) each element (and attribute) belongs to.

Comment: I did not enter the whole XML,sorry. It is YouTube playlist export XML and it starts with:

`<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' gd:etag='W/&quot;C04ESH47eCp7ImA9WhZWGUk.&quot;'>`

I am accessing XML in php, so I registered yt namespace:

`registerNamespace( 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' );`

It does not work in sense that I get an empty DOMNodeList upon making a query.

Thnx